# How to describe the practice of using "am-pluh-fi-key-shun" to indicate it's pronouncation?

Tags: names, phonetics

For instance, if we use [,æmplɪfɪ'keɪʃən] [,æmpləfə'keʃən] to indicate how to read "amplification", the practice is called phonetic notation or phonetic transcription, and the symbol is called International Phonetic Alphabet.

My questions are

1) How shall I describe the following practice:
"amplification is read as am-pluh-fi-key-shun"
Is there a **name** for the kind of phonetic notation?

2) what's the difference between [IPA] and [this kind of phonetic notation (am-pluh-fi-key-shun for amplification)] in terms of the degree of formality and/or which one is **more commonly used**?

3)Is it unanimous to use, for intance, -uh- for [ə] in this kind of notation? Maybe other people would write it as am-pli-fi-ki-shion or anything else?

Comment: It's not IPA, so drop that. Look for more clues on what the kind of pronunciation *amplification* (pron.: *am-pluh-fi-key-shun*) is called. Let us know what you found.

Comment: Question 3) is not difficult to find. "pronunciation of ipa symbols" yields [this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:IPA_pronunciation_key) as the first result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of pronunciation help is called a **pronunciation respelling**. Unlike IPA, it’s not actually a transliteration as such, since it doesn’t use one system of writing to represent something from a different system of writing: it uses *the same* system of writing to (attempt to) resolve ambiguities within that system itself.

The advantage of a pronunciation respelling is that the system is immediately familiar to anyone familiar with the language, since it uses the language’s own orthography as basis. The disadvantage, especially in a language like English, is that it is less precise and more likely to be ambiguous than a true phonetic transliteration which, as oerkelens points out, is language-agnostic and based on the acoustic/enunciatory details of each individual sound.

Wikipedia has [a very useful article on pronunciation respellings for English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_respelling_for_English), which has a tabular overview of some of the standardised respelling systems that are or have been commonly used for English.

Answer (score 0):

The IPA is the same for all languages and dialects. The kind of semi-phonetic transliteration you propose is very much dependant on language and dialect. For example, most English speakers would pronounce your *key* as [kɪ:] instead of [keɪ].

That means that if you want to use such a transcription system, your correspondence table would have to be different for every audience you want to address, depending on how *they* would "naturally" pronounce the letters you choose. In practice, this is messy and leads to misunderstandings (I would pronounce the word *amplification* wrong based on your transcription, for instance.)

By the way, where you mention *alphabets*, I'm pretty sure you mean *letters*. An alphabet is a full collection of letters that are used to write a language (or several languages), e.g. the modern Greek alphabet consists of 24 letters.

Comment: Essentially a helpful commentary.

Comment: The syllables used are invariably those that are familiar to everyone so they may aid in easy understanding of the pronunciation by comparison.

Comment: You neglect to mention that the IPA, while the same for every language, is not something most people know by heart. But writing the word like "am-pluh-fi-key-shun" would make it instantly recognisable for anyone who knows English. Not to mention the difficulties in writing IPA with a normal keyboard.

Comment: So your suggestion for the name is “semi-phonetic translation”？

Comment: Essentially a helpful commentary = Doesn't answer the question.